# In After Effects alpha does not apply to a PNG layer with a button image

Tags: after-effects

I have 4 PNG layers (3 display text and 1 displays a button) in AE. When I apply rectangle + alpha it works for text, but when I apply alpha to button, the rectangular does not disappear but becomes as a size of the button. How to solve this?